# REST web method in fiddler parameter is null

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, fiddler

Below is the fiddler request i composed. i have also added my class contract and method signature. problem is when i execute request, i get null parameter in method.

```
POST /Service.svc/getPackPreviews HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.8.101:4444
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 22

{"Type":"all" , "RegionId":0,  "CategoryId":0, "Radius":0,  "LatLong":"12"}
```

**Contract**

```
[DataContract]
public class PackFilter
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; } //e.g. distance, category, region

    [DataMember]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Radius { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LatLong { get; set; }
}
```

**Method:**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    List<string> getPackPreviews(PackFilter filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my Comment is not enabled for in SO... I am trying to help you posting it as an answer....**Try this** ...see if this work... @Hammad Nasir

```
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<string> getPackPreviews(PackFilter filter){}
```

Comment: I am already doing this .        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
       List<string> getPackPreviews(PackFilter filter){}

Comment: remove the BodyStyle from the attribute... @HammadNasir

Answer (score 0):

Is *UriTemplate* specified? As far as URI (/Service.svc/getPackPreviews) is concerned, in rest services it is not a good practice to use verb in method's name such as get, update etc. Make use of noun such as for instance Products/Employees/Bidders which can be invoked by diffrent requests get/post/delete. 
Make sure RequestFormat property is set to Json, it defaults to XML.